# Orders page is not showing up data - Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento2

There is a Magento project that was working perfectly fine before this morning until it suddenly started giving an error on "Orders" page in Magento admin. Problem is, it keeps loading forever, with no menu tabs working after landing on this page.

[image]

Here is the output of the console:

[image]

I have also tried like reindexing but couldn't make it work.

Any suggestions as to why it shows like this?

Comment: Can you check the log file? Is it possible to see your website?

Comment: @Satish: Try to run deployment queries once.

Comment: Tried it but not working.. table started showing but data is not loading up.. any ideas?